# How can I remove texture from walls?

Tags: walls

How do I remove wall texture in my kitchen? I don't know where to begin. Should I sand or skim coat?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you (e.g. pictures, what the walls are built on, etc). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I've revised your post a bit. I seriously doubt you have unpainted acoustical texture on your walls. That's what "popcorn" is. Feel free to edit again with more detail.

Comment: Depends on what kind of texture we're talking about. Some can be scraped off, others need sanded.

Comment: If it's NOT plaster and lathe, you might consider ripping out the drywall and replacing it...if it's really stuck on hard.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to wet the surface using a sprayer, wait a few minutes for the material to soften, the scrape off using a scraper.

You may need to do some touch-up of the drywall after removing the "popcorn" which you can do with spackle for small imperfections or drywall compound for larger ones.

Be sure to test on a small area to be sure it's going to work properly before you wet a large area.

Also, be aware that some of these used asbestos.  If you are in doubt, have it tested!

Comment: That might be useful advice for unpainted acoustical texture. I really doubt that's what we're talking about here. I've never seen it on walls.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume it’s a painted painted wall. Sanding will be extremely difficult as the paint will gum up whatever you are using to sand. You could try a product like Krud Kutter but from personal experience, if the wall is more than 20 sq feet or so, you’re probably better of skim coating. It’ll probably take at least two passes. Always a good idea to scuff up the wall a bit with a coarse sand paper—especially if you’ve got a semi or full gloss paint.